# How to handle file upload with possibility of pre-adding/-deleting images

Tags: javascript, html, image, file

Our users have a `<input type="file" multiple>` to select some images. These images will be rendered as thumbnails in a list below.

```
┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐
│ 1 ││ 2 ││ 3 ││ 4 │
└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘
```

The user can then use the file input again to select **additional** images. These will be added to the thumbnail list below.

```
┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐
│ 1 ││ 2 ││ 3 ││ 4 ││ a ││ b ││ c ││ d │
└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘
```

Also he has the possiblity to delete some of the previously selected files from the thumbnail list, so only the images which he really wants remain.

```
┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐
│ 1 ││ 2 ││ a ││ c │
└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘
```

I'm using the `File` objects to capture, what images are in the list and which are not.

But how can I handle the file upload itself? Is it possible to submit only the remaining images through the form with creating a new `<input type="file" multiple>` and filling it with the `File` objects I got from the user? (I know there is a security limitation, but my `File` objects are directly from the user?)

Could I create multiple `<input type="file" multiple>` (a new one after each user selection) and remove the deleted images after the submit on the server? (Downside would be the unneeded payload, because the "deleted" images will still be uploaded)

Or do I have to use ajax for uploading the `File` objects? Would it be bad practice to submit the base64-data of the images in `<input type="hidden">`s with the form to avoid ajax?

Comment: Are you accessing files using `INPUT_ELEMENT.files` ?

Comment: Yes, in the `onchange` event of the `input` I read the `this.files` und display the thumbnails through `FileReader`

Comment: `this.files` is `readonly` object. On remove, save the deleted image in hidden input field and while processing it over server side, exclude those images..

Comment: Could this lead into server side restrictions regarding upload size and count (so if the user selects 1000 images and deletes 999 of them, then all 1000 would be submitted).

Comment: Yes, but I doubt there is any other way around..Le me know if you find any..You could go through implementation/approach of DROPZONE..I'm not sure how they deal with this..Or may be they upload every image on `change` and then delete it from server if removed..

Comment: I think they use ajax. As far as I know, you can add specific `File` objects to the form data for a XHR. Unfortunately it would make my situation much more complicated, so I'll try out your solution and come back to you later this day. Thanks so far.

Comment: Works like a charm. Everytime the user selects images, I hide the old file-input and create a new one, in which the user can select more images. At the same time I remember in hidden inputs, what images (index) the user deleted. Server-side I then filter the uploaded files.

Thanks for your help! If you want, you can post your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: I don't think it can be an answer..I'm glad you cracked it..